# How to fold lines above the current unless it has less indentation than the current

Tags: vimscript, folding

My intention is to facilitate investigation of deeply buried code.

For example, an error is thrown with message "ABC Error" and if `|` is where the cursor is:

```
function handleRequest(req) {
  let param = req.toJSON();
  if ( param['get'] ) {
    param['data'].sanitize()
      .then( d => {
        ...
      })
      .catch( e => { alert("ABC Error") });|
```

I want the end result to be something like

```
function handleRequest(req) {
  if ( param['get'] ) {
    param['data'].sanitize()
      .catch( e => { alert("ABC Error") });|
```

The algorithm would be like, getting the `indent('.')` and find lines above and fold it -- unless it has a lower indent, and update the current indent until the current indent level reaches 0.  (I know that this would not work very well with `else` clauses)

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking for a command/function/mapping that creates a new fold when using `foldmethod=manual`? I'm also not sure what you mean by "update the current indent until the current indent level reaches 0"

Comment: I need a way to fold the lines so I can see how the program flows (in this case, how the error is thrown) -- so any of command / function / mapping / plugin is ok.  The algorithm is going from the current line (ideally) top of the function, like `.catch` has indent level 3, and go up fold the lines (since `.then` and subsequent lines are 3 or above.  Then we show `param['data']...` as it is level 2. So update the current indent to 2 and continue go up. Level 1 for `if ( param..` thus folding lines >=1 above it. Please feel free to edit to make it clearer :)

Comment: I *think* I understand your algorithm now. But I'm still unclear on if you want something that you manually invoke in specific situations when you want to create a fold, or something that automatically creates folds for an entire file (using syntax or expression folding).

Comment: Oops sorry. I want something that can be manually invoked.